# How to prevent Word 2013 from detecting a comma used as a thousands separator as a grammar mistake?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2013, spell-check

I have a text, which contains a lots of numbers, in which a comma is used as a thousands separator like this: `1,000`, meaning `one thousand`. When I check spelling and grammar Word underlines these numbers with blue curly underline and offers to to add a space after the comma (`1,000` becomes `1, 000`). Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: What is your system language set to?

Comment: @Burgi - Bulgarian.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the language you are using the coma could be used as a sparator for decimal instead of thousands.

The first thing to do is check your spelling corrector language and if in this language the correct separator is coma(,) or dot(.).

If the previous doesn't solve your problem you can try to put the numbers using the `Formula` option in word.

Answer (score 0):

Under Options/Advanced I changed Numeral from "Context" back to "Arabic", which I think is the default, and the weird question marks magically disappeared!!

Comment: How does this relate to the question?